# API call and DB operation order

Tags: rest, transactions, distributed-transactions

I have a theoritical question.

I have a normal HTTP request on a site backend, which does some business logic (e.g. changes data - all wrapped in a transaction) and in this process, calls a RESTful WS, which is a POST so changes data on the other site, other db as well.

I'm a bit concerned about consistency.

What if WS succeeds, but the process which is calling it, can't commit. I can commit the process first, but in that case, i have to worry about the WS failing.

So my question is, what is the standard to handle these kind of situations?

Comment: How will "What if WS succeeds, but the process which is calling it, can't commit." ever happen? Wouln't the WS *fail* if the commit fails?

Comment: I meant that the WS succeeds (don't forget, other DB, other system), and my own transaction, in my own database fails.

Comment: Sounds like you are out of luck.

Comment: :) Yes, that was my worry as well. :D